# Using rowid in a delete statement

Tags: oracle, sql-delete

Is there any SEVERE contraindications to delete using rowid?

```
DELETE FROM NETATEMP.SFAC_TESTATA_CASISTICHE
      WHERE ROWID IN (  SELECT MIN (ROWID)
                          FROM NETATEMP.SFAC_TESTATA_CASISTICHE
                      GROUP BY ID_CASO,
                               DESCRIZIONE_TECNICA,
                               DESCRIZIONE_ANALISI,
                               PDF,
                               SCARTI,
                               DATA_INIZIO_ANALISI,
                               DATA_FINE_ANALISI,
                               DATA_INSTRADAMENTO,
                               DATA_RISOLUZIONE,
                               STRINGA_RICERCA,
                               SETTIMANA,
                               DATA_INIZIO_SETT,
                               DATA_FINE_SETT,
                               FATTURAZIONE,
                               IN_ELABORAZIONE
                        HAVING COUNT (1) > 1);
```

Comment: are you assuming that a "lower" rowid is an earlier record (min)?

Comment: @tbone: no, the records are identical. It doesn't matter wich was created first. I often use min to choose a random record

Answer (score 9, accepted):

If you assume that `min(rowid)` returns the "earliest" row, then yes, you have a problem (because it won't)

If you use `min(rowid)` only to get one of the duplicates (and you don't care which), then no, there is nothing wrong with that statement.

Comment: @Gik25 you can refer to the link in my answer for more info

Comment: @Gik25: `min` works to select exactly one (arbitrary) row. It will ***not*** select the "oldest" because the ROWID does not reflect any timeline of inserting or updating.

Answer (score 2):

A few things to be aware of.  It seems you are depending on the rowid to give you the earliest row for your particular grouping (select min(rowid) ...).  This won't always be true.  The only way to guarantee you are deleting the earliest record is to use some column (like timestamp) that you can order by.  [Tom Kyte explains this](http://asktom.oracle.com/pls/asktom/f?p=100:11:0%3a%3a%3a%3aP11_QUESTION_ID:912210644860) better than I could.

> A rowid implies NOTHING other than the location of the row physically.
>   It does not imply age,  order of insertion, or anything like that.

Also, depending on the size of the table, you will generate a lot of redo/undo, and it may be beneficial in large tables to use pl/sql to delete in chunks and commit every x rows.

Just my thoughts

Comment: Deleting in chunks generates **more** redo and undo (in total) than doing it in a single transaction. That's an old myth that wasn't true 20 years ago and isn't still

Comment: my point wasn't to generate less overall redo, it was to CONTROL it better.  I've had several cases where a large single delete was running for hours, then DBAs had to kill it, and the time needed to rollback everything took a LONG LONG time.  For large deletes, its a "nicer" way of treating the db environment imo (and pisses off the DBAs less ;-).  Much easier to stop/restart if needed.  Just my experience anyway.

Comment: but you leave your data in an inconsitent state (because you half "partial" transactions - from a logical point of view). If that is OK for you and if you can do that with all FK constraints enabled then so be it.

Comment: again, just my actual experience on what works vs what doesn't (at least for the large db environments I've worked with).  We'll just have to agree to disagree I suppose.